# How to remove the menu-bar always top effect?

Tags: html, css

I m using this template .This link contains a live demo .

http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page207/wpf-degree

However , I want to remove the menubar always top effect .

For its style.css

```
/*--------.menu_area-------- */
.menu_area{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
   font-size: 17px; /*--------.monchhichi-------- */
   font-weight:bold;
   color:#CBE32D;


}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px; 
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #CBE32D;
  border-color: transparent;
}
#navbar{overflow-x: hidden;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #244a66;  /*--------.monchhichi menu bar font color-------- */
  font-family:"arial",sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #48575a; 
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before { 
  border-bottom: 15px solid #48575a; 
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: -15px;
  width: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu li a {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  display: block;  
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: medium none;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
  background-color:transparent;  
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown-menu > .active > a, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;  
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

It doesn't contain `position :fixed` or `z-value` features .

I don't know why always-top effect activates here.

..............................................................................................................................................................

Comment: try to remove the top:-15px; in the  .navbar-nav > li >

Comment: May be you need to remove class .navbar-fixed-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the files. There are multiple CSS files linked in `index.php`, you will find the CSS of navigation bar in this file

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Remove `navbar-fixed-top` from the `index.php` file or make a custom css file to overwrite bootstrap style, without changing the code in core `css/bootstrap.min.css` file.

Answer (score 1):

You Just need to remove one class from nav tag

Find this in your template's Code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

and just remove one class  navbar-fixed-top

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
```